# Output of multiple post and pre increments in one statement

Tags: c, increment, operator-precedence, post-increment, pre-increment

I'm new to C language so please sum1 help me out.
A C code written

```
int i=3;
printf("%d",++i + ++i);
```

Complier gives O/P =9. How?

Comment: why do you think it doesn't give that result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results are undefined. You're modifying a variable more than once in an expression (or [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) to be more accurate).

Modifying a variable more than once between sequence points is undefined, so don't do it.

It might be your compiler, for this particular case decides to evalate
`++i + ++i` as

- increment the last `++i` , yielding 4, leaving i to be 4
- increment the first `++i`, yielding 5, leaving i to be 5 (as the prior step left i as 4, incrementing it to 5)
- sum the two values, 4 + 5.

Another compiler, or if you alter the optimization level, or if you change the code slightly, might produce different output.

Comment: agreed: I checked my gcc 4.1.2 and recv'd the value 10 (which could be just as easily explained as your 9)

Comment: @KevinDTimm could you please explain how would you account for `10`?

Comment: @ajay - yes, the standard says that this results in undefined behavior.  So, any result is equally (in)valid.

Comment: @KevinDTimm Yes, it is undefined behaviour and anything can happen because the standard imposes no requirement on the implementation. I was just wondering about `which could be just as easily explained as your 9` part in your comment.