# Post/pre increments in 'printf'

Tags: c++, c, operator-precedence

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Output of multiple post and pre increments in one statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812850/output-of-multiple-post-and-pre-increments-in-one-statement)
>   [Post-increment and pre-increment in 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706199/post-increment-and-pre-increment-in-for-loop)

The following code snippet

```
int i=0;
printf("%d %d",i++,i++);
```

gives the output

1 0

I can understand that, but the following

```
int i=0;
printf("%d %d",++i,++i);
```

gives the output

2 2

Can someone explain me the second behavior?

Comment: This is starting to smell a lot like homework, especially after your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706199/post-increment-and-pre-increment-in-for-loop

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812850/output-of-multiple-post-and-pre-increments-in-one-statement

Comment: Im just learning C after long time again from scratch and I get these doubts :D

Comment: Maybe the best answer to cross-reference is [Undefined behaviour and sequence points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both printfs invoke undefined-behavior. See this : [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Quoted from this link:

> In short, undefined behaviour means
>   anything can happen from daemons
>   flying out of your nose to your
>   girlfriend getting pregnant.

For newbies : **Don't ever try to modify values of your variables *twice or more* in a function call argument-list**. For details, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) to know what it means. :-)

Answer (score 3):

They're both undefined behaviour. Modifying the variable `i` more than once is undefined. Also, C++ or C? You need to make up your mind as the behaviour of pre-increment I believe is different between them.

Answer (score 1):

You got what called 'undefined behaviour', because you are changing the same variable more than once between sequence points. Another compiler can give you different results.